# I am not able to color cells with Styler and also change the font size at the same time. But if done on its own its possible

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, pandas-styles

Problem: I can't use **.applymap** and **.set_properties** / **.set_table_styles** at the same Time.

When I only color the different cells wit .applymap(color_cell) it works perfectly fine, but if I also want to change font-size and align the text. Then my Cells arent colored anymore.

Where is my mistake?

```
def color_cell(val):
    color = "#90EE90" if val > 0 else "#FF6600"
    return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

```
styled = result.style.set_properties(**{'font-size': '10pt'})
styled = styled.set_properties(**{'index_header': {'font-size': '14pt'}})
styled = styled.set_properties(**{'column_header': {'font-size': '14pt'}})
styled = styled.set_table_styles([{'selector': 'th', 'props': [('text-align', 'center')]}])
styled = styled.applymap(color_cell)
html = styled.render()
```

Comment: `.set_properties(**{'index_header': {'font-size': '14pt'}})` and `.set_properties(**{'column_header': {'font-size': '14pt'}})` will create invalid CSS. `index_header {'font-size'; column_header: {'font-size';` since `set_properties` expects only valid CSS properties and values as kwargs. What are you trying to do with those lines?

Comment: @HenryEcker I want to change color of the different cells. And change the size of the index and column and also in every cell align the text to the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [10000000, -20000000],
        "col2": [-40000000, 50000000],
        "col3": [70000000, -80000000],
        "col4": [100000000, 110000000],
        "col5": [-130000000, 140000000],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it without the need for `set_properties`:

```py
df.style.set_table_styles(
    [
        {"selector": "th", "props": [("text-align", "center"), ("font-size", "14pt")]},
        {"selector": "td.index", "props": [("font-size", "14pt")]},
        {"selector": "td", "props": [("font-size", "10pt")]},
    ]
).applymap(color_cell)
```

Which outputs in a Jupyter notebook cell:

[image]